# Excel VBA - Check if cell contains specific characters

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I'm using the following to check if a cell contains any invalid characters.

```
If Target Like "*[\!%^:~#|@.;`\/*$,]*" Then
```

This works fine and return the correct error message.

I'd like to add Double Quotes " to the check, but when I add " I get errors.

How do I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just substitute them?

Comment: How did you add the double quote?  You should be able to add it inside the character class, but you may have to "double" it as is usual in VBA when adding a literal doiuble quote to a text string.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez I've tried to ensure they are updated.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I simply added " which then caused the error. Did thing to add it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubling the quotes should do it:

```
Like "*[\!%^:~#|@.;`\/*$,""]*"
```

Note that \ is the LIKE escape char, so "\!" means in fact "!".

Test:

```
a = "abc""de"
? a
abc"de
? a like "*[b]*"
True
? a like "*[""]*"
True
```

Comment: `Like "*[\!%^:~#|@.;\`\/*$,""]*"` would equal `Like "*[\!-%*,.\/:;@^\`|~]*"`... untested though but the ascii-table would made me believe we can create that range. It would make at least the double asterisk unneccesary.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez Thanks that works and for spotting the \!  it shouldn't have had the slash in front of it.

Comment: @JvdV Thx for the alternative pattern in comment *(think you referred to double quotes instead of asterisks)*, but what exactly would make the *double* **quotes**  therein unnecessary?

Comment: @T.M. the quotes would be in the range between `!-%` on the ascii-table and therfor you'd not have to write all characters in that range. And yes, I meant quotes! Thanks for the question.